# Change File Descriptor to pipe STDOUT to a Socket?

Tags: c, file-io, client-server, file-descriptor

I've got a socket open, which connects a client and the server.

I'm implementing remote execution, and so I want to change the file descriptor table such that calls which would normally go to stdout, actually go across the socket to be output on the client.

Right now i have the server fork, and then use the system() command to execute whatever command.

What do i have to do to manipulate the file descriptor table?

Here is the code I am working with:

I am using select. The socket I am using is the one returned by the accept call (this is all server side).

```
            dup2(S,1);

            int retval = fork();
            if (retval > 1)
            {
            system(receive.text);
            return 0;
            }
```

Now the result of this, is that no text is printed to the server (so its obviously not hooked into the stdout of the server), but neither is anything displayed on the client).

Do i have to do anything more on the client side to get this out (like a recv() call?), and am I using the right socket?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The usual mechanism is `dup2(2)`:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int dup(int oldfd);
int dup2(int oldfd, int newfd);
```

The `dup(2)` call will duplicate the given filedescriptor to the lowest-numbered open filedescriptor. This was the historical mechanism, still works, but it doesn't make it easy to specify file descriptor numbers. So `dup2(2)` was introduced to allow specifying both filedescriptors.

You could use it like this:

```
int s = /* connect() or accept() */
int ret = dup2(s, 1);
/* exec() */
```

Comment: @blackbinary, you're making me regret just using an integer rather than `STDOUT_FILENO` :) -- `0` is stdin, `1` is stdout, and `2` is stderr; I find it easier to remember because of the `2>&1` style of shell redirection -- you almost never redirect `0`, so that must be input. :)

Comment: okay, then the page I was looking at had a typo (had 0 instead of 1). I'm going to post some code in the original post because its still not behaving correctly.

Comment: @Blackbinary, the page might have also wanted standard input to work for the command.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `system` merely keeps the parent's file descriptors, so it cannot work like you want. You could use `popen`, but it's ugly. You really should write the `fork` and `exec` code yourself. `system` is almost always a mistake.

Comment: Ah, i thought it was equivalent, and I was just saving the time. So if i fork and exec myself, it should work?

Comment: So, if dup2 is used to change the file descriptor, why can't I then just use a printf (since that will now be pointed at the socket)? It dosn't work, but I'd like to know why (and I can't seem to get the fork and exec way to work either).